# how to make a prompt filter that can filter files using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

there are 3 files in ~/path/:

~/path/Record_1

```
A ON
B ON
C ON
```

~/path/Record_2

```
A ON
B OFF
C ON
```

~/path/Record_3

```
A OFF
B OFF
C ON
```

I hope a shell script can do that:

```
   $ ./myfilter
    Do you want to turn A ON? (y/n) 'y'
```

If I enter 'y', ~/path/Record_1 and ~/path/Record_2 would show up

```
~/path/Record_1
~/path/Record_2
```

After this step, script will automatically ask the following question

```
Do you want to turn B ON? (y/n) 'y'
```

If I enter 'y' again, script would search file that contain 'B ON' from the **last step**. hence the final result should be as follows.

```
 ~/path/Record_1
```

It is easy to use grep to get 'A ON', but the most difficult point is that how to filter files from **last step**?

Comment: You could use a bash array for the filtered files, where you remove unneeded elements in each filter step.

Comment: ok, let me try it.